# Refresh dynamically created table

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, fullcalendar, refresh

I want to refresh the dynamically created table once the value stored into the database. I tried like below:

```
  $('#caseTbl tr').each(function(){
        $(this).droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
            accept: "#serviceTechs tr",
            over: function(event, ui) {
                var $this = $(this);
            },
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var caseNo=$(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                var servTechName=$(ui.draggable).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                updateDB(caseNo,servTechName);
            },

        });
    });
    function updateDB(caseNo,servTechName){
        alert("CaseNo>> "+caseNo+ " || servTechName>> "+servTechName);
        var caseObj=new sforce.SObject("Case");
        var stechQuery=sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id from Service_Technician__c Where Name ='"+servTechName+"' LIMIT 1");
        stRecord=stechQuery.getArray('records');
        stechId=stRecord[0].Id;
        var caseQuery=sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id from Case Where CaseNumber ='"+caseNo+"' LIMIT 1");
        caseRecord=caseQuery.getArray('records');
        caseObj.Id=caseRecord[0].Id;
        caseObj.Assigned_To__c=stechId;
        alert("stechObj>> "+caseObj.Assigned_To__c);
        sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);
        window.location.reload(); 
    }
```

instead of using this `window.location.reload();`, how to refresh the table alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via `Loading Page Fragments`. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
function RefreshTable() {
       $( "#YourTaleID" ).load( "yourpage.html #YourTaleID" );
   }
```

Comment: After using this function, I'm not able to drag the dynamically created table

Comment: reintialize your dragable event .  `$( "#YourTaleID" ).draggable();` after refresh table.

Comment: I tried like this: `function refreshCaseTable() {
            $( "#caseTbl" ).load( "#caseTbl" );
            $( "#caseTbl tr" ).draggable();
        }` but the dynamic table row is not able to drag